# Alternative to discontinued Brine-io (Python package for deep learning dataset management)

Tags: python, programming

I just found something I was always on the lookout for. [**Brine-io**](https://github.com/brine-io/brine) is a python package for dataset design, standardization and management for computer vision. It's author shows how to use it [here](https://medium.com/@hanrelan/a-non-experts-guide-to-image-segmentation-using-deep-neural-nets-dda5022f6282).

Sadly, the developer [stopped working on it.](https://medium.com/@hanrelan/hi-matheus-unfortunately-we-stopped-supporting-brine-so-the-brine-related-commands-wont-work-e32cc510dbd).

**Question:** Does anybody know of a python package that helps with creating and maintaining image datasets for computer vision?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Have you tried a Google search? There are a lot of Python deep learning packages. For instance I found this article: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/06/27/my-top-9-favorite-python-deep-learning-libraries/

Comment: @EricShain Shain this is not strictly about deep learning packages, but about preparing the data for use with packages, like in the article you linked.

Comment: @Izzy I'll see what I can do  about that.

Comment: One of the nice things about Open Source is that you, or anybody, can always fork the original package and start working on it again. If you do not have the necessary skills it is possible that you can find someone to work on it for you.

Comment: Do you know that Brine-io no longer works? Just because it is no longer maintained doesn’t mean it stops working.